# BufferedStream in WinRT?

Tags: c#, stream, windows-runtime, bufferedstream

Is there an equivalent of the `System.IO.BufferedStream` class for WinRT? The class itself isn't available, but is there a way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: @Alovchin, thanks! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use any of Windows Runtime streams with `AsStream...` extension methods. They create a "wrapper" streams that contain an internal buffer, and you can set its size. Refer to [Stream performance in C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994634.aspx#stream_performance) section of *Access the file system efficiently* MSDN document.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing the opposite (I need a `System.IO.Stream` around a WinRT stream); I had not realized that `AsStreamForRead` created a buffered stream, but the article you linked to makes it clear. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I misspelled those methods :) I meant `AsStream...` methods to wrap WinRT streams, of course :)